# Contradictional results from (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT())

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to split option value pair in SQL Server 2018, the results are good so far, but now I encountered some strange behaviour in `SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT()`.

The code is as following:

```
SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AgingFactorCorr:25',':')
SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AlarmBuzSignal:NA',':') 
SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AgingFactorCorr:25',':') ORDER BY VALUE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AlarmBuzSignal:NA',':') ORDER BY VALUE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

While running the first two SELECTs, the option is at row one and value at row two, for both pairs.

However, when applying `ORDER BY VALUE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`, the results are reversed.

For first one I get '25' as option, and for second one 'AlarmBuzSignal', the second one is desired.

What can be the reason of this behaviour? Can't see any difference besides datatypes maybe, but I don't think that should matter.

The problem hides in order by clause, after adding LEN(VALUE) DESC, for both I get the desired result, but doesn't seems like an elegant solutions to me.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ORDER BY VALUE for value's 'AgingFactorCorr' '25' is '25' definitely first.

Comment: What is the most elegant way to set first part of the pair as first row?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick. Run `SELECT @@VERSION` in Mgmt Studio to find out what your database engine's version is.

Comment: My bad, its 17 indeed, with SSMS 18

Comment: Questions aren't for answers, they are for questions. If you have answered the question yourself post an answer. Also note that [so] is **not** a forum; it does not work like one nor should be treated like one. Doing so can often result in a poor experience here.

Comment: I'm grateful for new information which can enhance my knowledge. 
My update is not processed I see, I posted it with Solved, remark.
I'm not treating it like a forum, maybe wrong word choice.

Comment: I removed the solution you added to your question @Arthur , along with your opening sentence about the site being a forum. It was *not* processed, it was just editted out by any user (me). [Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67492160/revisions)

Comment: Ah thank you.
Will improve my github practice.
"Answer your question", I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

when you don't provide order by statement , rows are returned randomly , and there is no guaranteed order of rows .
so for your first two select statements there is no guaranteed how the rows are going to be shown

if you order your first queries you will always get the same order in your result

> ```
> SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AgingFactorCorr:25',':')ORDER BY VALUE 
> SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AlarmBuzSignal:NA',':') ORDER BY VALUE 
> SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AgingFactorCorr:25',':') ORDER BY VALUE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
> SELECT VALUE o FROM STRING_SPLIT('AlarmBuzSignal:NA',':') ORDER BY VALUE OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
> ```

> ```
> | o               |
> | :-------------- |
> | 25              |
> | AgingFactorCorr |
>
> | o              |
> | :------------- |
> | AlarmBuzSignal |
> | NA             |
>
> | o  |
> | :- |
> | 25 |
>
> | o              |
> | :------------- |
> | AlarmBuzSignal |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e998c79043329a138fe0aec5d188a8a)*

from Microsoft Documentation:

> The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string. You can override the final sort order by using an ORDER BY clause on the SELECT statement (ORDER BY value).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: But still, the value should be retrieved as well.

Comment: think of adding a specific character before every option so group by will always return the same order. Then deleting it from the option string.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` `TOP (1)` will return an arbitrary row; it could be different **every time** you run the query. `STRING_SPLIT` is also documented to **not** maintain ordinal positions as well, so that only increases the arbitrary row you might get back.

Comment: Adding |OPT| in front of every option, then running replace(o,'|OPT|','') works like a charm.

However still not very happy with this solution.

It might be a performance killer, but in my case there are max 1000 rows, so it still runs within one second.

I see the cons and pros of solution provided by @eshirvana, even commented on that.

Comment: @Arthur still that trick won't help you , still you might get random orders

Comment: My suggestion is when you order a row with '|OPT|' and a row without it, that the row with |OPT| on it would be always at the same position. As I can see in front end it does work fine, so no need for me now to make it more complex.

Comment: But, as I said, not very happy with that.
If solution provided by @Larnu is the only way to go, I will give it a better look so I understand the mechanism of this process.

Comment: @Arthur yeah, not the best idea

Comment: I haven't posted any answers here @Arthur , only comments.

Comment: @eshirvana, yeah, so what is your advice?

Comment: You need to use a splitter that respects ordinal positions, @Arthur , like Smor shows in their answer.

Comment: @Larnu, so not to use strin_split(). Clear. Will do my best to understand it completely.
See not any answer of Smor :$

Comment: @Arthur - are you looking to only return the first part of the string only?  Or - do you need both values in separate rows?  If you only need the first part or the second part - and don't need or want additional rows - then using a string splitter isn't the way to do this.  A simple CHARINDEX will get the results much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately  [The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

You may want to use hand-made split instead. It returns a table of substrings with their positions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                  SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(N)
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1)) - 1,0) - s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

Borrowed from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Comment: I didn't downvote, but seems way too sophisticated to me.
Solution is already found, see my post.
Thank you for contribution

Comment: That other answer is *not* the solution @Arthur . It won't be consistent. If you don't understand the above, read the article Serg cited; it explains it very well.

Comment: Will examine it for sure, seems interesting and useful for big data.
I don't know if you can see my edit, but that's the solutions which suits my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue, which suits my case.

I'm not processing big data and the option value pair is alway of two rows, so I added |OPT| before every option then removing it with `replace(o,'|OPT|','')`.

As mentioned in the answers, there might a better way for delimiting strings.

I'm aware that my solution is heavy, in terms of performance.
Will do my best to improve that.